# React Native SQLite table not working with foreign keys

Tags: react-native, sqlite, foreign-keys

I'm making an app where a user can view movies/tv shows, and add them to a list they have pre-created.

I have an SQLite table that stores tv shows and movies, and their information (name, genres, summaries, etc.). I'll be referring to each row as an 'item'.

I have a page where users can create a list.

I have a page called Item.js where the user can click on the item, and see the information for that item. On the page is a picker to pick a list, and a button that should add that item to the list. I want to make it so that any list can have more than 1 item, and any item can be in more than 1 list (e.g., have a list called 'for my dad' and 'for my mum' with the same show on both).

The console is logging that it's created the table, but it doesn't do anything in relation to the addToList() function except print that it is being called. My issue seems to be in the SELECT function, because that isn't printing anything.

What am I missing?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import { DatabaseConnection } from '../Database/SQLDatabase';

const db = DatabaseConnection.getConnection();

db.exec(
  [{ sql: 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;', args: [] }], 
  false, 
  () =>   console.log('Foreign keys turned on') 
);

const Item = ({ route }) => {
  const { item } = route.params;

  const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState('');
  const [allLists, setAllLists] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name LIKE 'userList_%'`,
        [],
        (tx, results) => {
          console.log(results);
          const allLists = []
          for (let i=0; i < (results.rows ? results.rows.length : 0); i++){
            allLists.push(results.rows.item(i).name.slice(9));
          }
          setAllLists(allLists);
        }
      );
      tx.executeSql(
        `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS item_listsItsIn (
          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          list_name TEXT,
          item_name TEXT,
          list_id INTEGER,
          item_id INTEGER,
          FOREIGN KEY(list_id) REFERENCES userList_${selectedList}(listItem_id),
          FOREIGN KEY(item_id) REFERENCES table_items(id)
        )`,
        [],
        (tx, results) => {
          console.log('item_listsItsIn table created')
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      );
    })
  }, [selectedList])

  const addToList = () => {
    console.log('function called')
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(
          `SELECT listItem_id FROM userList_${selectedList} WHERE list_name = ?`,
          [selectedList],
          (tx, results) => {
            console.log('list id selected')
            const list_id = results.rows.item(0).listItem_id;
            tx.executeSql(
              'INSERT INTO item_listsItsIn (list_id, item_id, list_name, item_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
              [list_id, item.id, selectedList, item.name],
              (tx, results) => {
                console.log(`${item.name} has been added to ${selectedList}`)
              },
              (error) => {
                console.log(error);
              }
            )
          }
        )
      })
  }

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <View style={{width:'100%', height:200, backgroundColor:'grey'}}></View>
      <View style={styles.headers}>
        <Text style={styles.headersText}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.headersText}>{item.rating}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{marginLeft:20}}>
        <Text style={styles.category}>Type: </Text><Text>{item.type}</Text><Text style={styles.category}>Genres: </Text><Text>{item.genres}</Text><Text style={styles.category}>Release Year: </Text><Text>{item.year}</Text><Text style={styles.category}>Produced By: </Text><Text>{item.production}</Text><Text style={styles.category}>Creators: </Text><Text>{item.creators}</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{borderBottomColor:'grey', flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-around', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
        <View style={styles.picker}>
          <Picker mode="dropdown" selectedValue={selectedList} onValueChange={(selectedList) => setSelectedList(selectedList)}>
            <Picker.Item label="Select List" value="default" />
            {allLists.map((userList)=>(
              <Picker.Item label={userList} value={userList} key={userList} />
            ))}
          </Picker>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={addToList} style={styles.buttons} disabled={!selectedList} >
          <Text style={{fontSize:16, color:'white', fontWeight:'bold'}}>Add To List</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={{borderBottomColor:'grey', flexDirection:'column', borderBottomWidth:1}}>
        <View style={styles.headers}>
          <Text style={styles.headersText}>Summary</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{alignSelf:'center', width:'90%'}}>
          <Text style={{letterSpacing:2, marginBottom:20}}>{item.summary}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
        <View style={styles.headers}>
          <Text style={styles.headersText}>Cast</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{alignSelf:'center', width:'90%'}}>
          
        </View>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  )
}

export default Item
```